# Send & receive video between Python and Rust via UNIX socket

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, rust, ipc

The final requirement is to create a system which can stream video footage via a UNIX IPC socket from Python to Rust. The Python script has exclusive access to the camera/video. I'm pretty new to Rust.

I have tried an approach wherein the control flows as follows:

- In Python, as the video flows in, strip each frame out of it to convert it into a NumPy array
- Then, convert it into a string. Then to bytes.
- Send it over a UNIX IPC socket.
- At the receiving end, convert it back into string.
- Hopefully parse it to get a usable array and make an image from it.

Sender:

```py
import socket, os, cv2, numpy
# print all the string without truncating
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.inf)

# declare the camera socket and unlink path if already in use
camera_socket_path = '/home/user/exps/test.sock'
try:
    os.unlink(camera_socket_path)
except OSError:
    pass

# create and listen on the socket
camera_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
camera_socket.bind(camera_socket_path)
camera_socket.listen()

conn, addr = camera_socket.accept()

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('example.mp4')
success, image = vidcap.read()
print(str(image))
while success:
    conn.send(bytes(str(image), 'utf-8'))      
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    break # after sending a frame, for testing

conn.close()
```

Receiver:

```rust
use std::os::unix::net::UnixStream;
use std::io::prelude::*;

use image::RgbImage;
use ndarray::Array3;

fn array_to_image(arr: Array3<u8>) -> RgbImage {
    assert!(arr.is_standard_layout());

    let (height, width, _) = arr.dim();
    let raw = arr.into_raw_vec();

    RgbImage::from_raw(width as u32, height as u32, raw)
        .expect("container should have the right size for the image dimensions")
}

fn main() {
    // create a standard UNIX IPX socket stream
    let mut stream = UnixStream::connect("/home/user/exps/test.sock").unwrap();

    loop {
        // 2074139 is the length of the string printed at sender :D
        // I thought it might work out but it didn't obviously
        // the docs suggest an exponential of 2. default was 1024
        let mut buf = [0; 2074139];
        let count = stream.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
        let response = String::from_utf8(buf[..2074139].to_vec()).unwrap();
        // write a parser function to convert the string to Array3 iterating through line()
        // let pic = array_to_image(convert(response));
        println!("{}", response);
        break; // get a single frame, for testing
    }
}
```

Both the strings look nothing like each other. In the final version, I hope to create a stream using which I can continuously do this for incoming video stream from a camera, with something like `cv2.VideoCapture()`. What is the list of stuff to be done to achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

An mp4 file consists of arbitrary byte sequences, not utf8 strings. So you should send the raw bytes and receive into a `Vec<u8>` or similar data type.

There is no reason to mangle things through a string encodings, unix sockets support arbitrary bytes.

For debugging purposes you can print out the bytes in hex format, but you shouldn't *send* it as such since that too would be wasteful.